# Timestamp of last run from Feed Me-feed

Tags: plugin-feedme

I have multiple feeds being run via cronjobs, and would like to display front end "Last updated: 15:38 18. June"

Does anyone know if its possible to get the timestamp of the last import from a specific Feed Me feed?

I've found the following from the docs, but it seems to be pointed towards running a feed. I just want to get data out of the log from a feed.

```
{% set params = {
    url: 'http://path.to/feed/',
    type: 'xml',
    element: 'entry',
    cache: 60,
} %}

{% set feed = craft.feedme.feed(params) %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information that shows up on in the `admin/feed-me/logs` portion of your Control Panel is pulled directly from the Feed Me logs on the filesystem at `storage/logs/feedme.log`.

So you'd need to write a little [plugin](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/extend/) that parsed those files and exposed the data you want back to the template to display it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Brad! That makes sense. Then I will look into that.